# @ command does not work in SQL PLUS (OS HP-unix)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql file (abc.sql) which contains some code. I am able to run this using "run" command as

```
SQL> run abc.sql
  1* select 1 from dual

         1

SQL>
```

But not able to execute using "@" command. If i execute using @ it just return to the SQL prompt without executing this file.

```
SQL>  @abc.sql
SQL>
SQL>
```

Could you please help me in resolving this issue?

FYI, I m using Oracle 8.1.7.4.0 on HP-unix (Tru64 UNIX V5.1B (Rev. 2650)

Answer (score 1):

within your file do have

```
select 1 from dual
/
```

you need to tell the sql engine to execute the line (/)

**Edit**

after the @ type in "EDIT" and see what the buffer says:

```
SQL> @a.sql

         1
----------
         1

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

...

select 1 from dual
/
```

Comment: @Chandra Bhushan updated above, what happens when you "edit" (or "ed") after the @abc.sql

Answer (score 1):

`run` does not execute a file's content. Rather, it runs the content of the buffer.

The docu (
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve037.htm#sthref1803 ) says

**R[UN]**

Lists and executes the SQL command or PL/SQL block currently stored in the SQL buffer.

The buffer has no command history list and does not record SQL*Plus commands.

*Usage*

RUN causes the last line of the SQL buffer to become the current line.

The slash command (/) functions similarly to RUN, but does not list the command in the SQL buffer on your screen. The SQL buffer always contains the last SQL statement or PL/SQL block entered.

---

You are probably misstaking `run` for the `start` command.

Comment: My question here is i m not able to execute using "@". Can u plz tell me the reason?

Comment: And you can believe whatever René Nyffenegger tells you about SQL*Plus.

Comment: @Chandra Bhushan: Probably having the contents of your file `abc.sql` could help.

Comment: set termout on and execute abc.sql (SQL>@abc.sql) it gives output. Thanks all for valuable suggestions.